# C calculator program is outputting 0

Tags: c, constants

Trying to make a simple program that calculates the amount of weight lost over a given amount of days using a constant variable. Everything looks right to me but it's outputting 0 as the answer? Any help would be much appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

double days; //declaring variables that will be enetred by user
const float weightLoss = 0.04; //declaring constant to be used in calculation
float overallLoss; //float that is used to display overall result

printf("Please enter how many days you are going to fast for: \n"); 
scanf("%f", &days); //scans keyboard for input and assigns to designated variable
printf("You entered: %f\n", days); 

overallLoss = days * weightLoss; 

printf("You will lose %.2f stone", overallLoss); //print of the final result

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `double days;`, so you need `scanf("%lf", &days)`.  Or you can use `float days;` with the current format.

With `printf()`, you don't need the `l`; with `scanf()`, it is crucial.

Don't forget to end outputs with a newline; your last `printf()` is missing one.  Also, some compilers (GCC and clang, for example) will provide warnings about such mismatches between the format string and the types provided.  Make sure you're using the appropriate options (`gcc -Wall`, for example) to get them diagnosed.

#### Working code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    double days;
    const float weightLoss = 0.04; // Dimension: stone per day
    float overallLoss;

    printf("Please enter how many days you are going to fast for: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &days) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Oops!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("You entered: %13.6f\n", days);

    overallLoss = days * weightLoss;

    printf("You will lose %.2f stone\n", overallLoss);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample output

First run:

```
Please enter how many days you are going to fast for: 12
You entered:     12.000000
You will lose 0.48 stone
```

Second run:

```
Please enter how many days you are going to fast for: a fortnight
Oops!
```

You can forego the `if` test if you've not learned about those yet as long as you type the input accurately; it must be a recognizable number.

#### Alternative code

Using `float days` instead of `double days`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    float days;
    const float weightLoss = 0.04; // Dimension: stone per day
    float overallLoss;

    printf("Please enter how many days you are going to fast for: ");
    if (scanf("%f", &days) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Oops!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("You entered: %13.6f\n", days);

    overallLoss = days * weightLoss;

    printf("You will lose %.2f stone\n", overallLoss);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample output

```
Please enter how many days you are going to fast for: 10
You entered:     10.000000
You will lose 0.40 stone
```

Comment: I am still getting 0 as my output.

Comment: That is more puzzling.  What did you type as the input?  You should check the return value from `scanf()`, as in: `if (scanf("%lf", %days) != 1) { fprintf(stderr, "Oops!\n"); exit(1); }`.

Comment: I'm typing multiples of 10 as inputs. I would use an if but I haven't started to learn how to use those yet.

Comment: Works fine for me with `float days;`. Apparently I can achieve complete weightlessness by fasting for 365 days :-)

Comment: Thank you @squeamishossifrage this worked! Not sure why I would have to use a float for a whole number but if it works then I am not going to question it.

Comment: Thank you @JonathanLeffler for your hard work as well, much obliged!

Comment: Are you on an esoteric platform?  Are you using an archaic compiler?  Are you sure you're running the fixed code?  It is hard to see how entering a multiple of 10 into the fixed code could go wrong.